# Modification of spite node sizes when I change scene

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

In my app I've 2 scenes.
I use the first scene as menu scene so I create a button for presents the second scene.
But when I present the second scene the sizes of all elements of this scene they become bigger than the sizes that I've set.

The first picture is the second scene which it was presented by first scene.
The second picture is the second scene which it wasn't presented by first scene.

[image: this is the second scene which it was presented by first scene][image: this is the second scene which it wasn't presented by first scene]

I want to presente the second scene from the first scene, but I want that the objects sizes are like the objects in the second scene which is showed by second picture.
In the second scene the object sizes have been set from me.

I understood and I've done in this way:

```
 class GameViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {

        if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "MainScene") {

            let gameScene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")

            gameScene?.scaleMode = .aspectFill
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

            view.presentScene(scene)
        }

        view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Investigate the scene's `.scaleMode` in each of your two situations... you may need to reconfigure it.

Comment: I’ve updated my code

Comment: can you make a sample project that demonstrates just the problem